# Jenkins + Force.com Migration Tool - REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG

Tags: force.com, ant, migration-tool, jenkins, ci

I am currently receiving a REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG error when using the Force.com Mirgration Tool and Ant with Jenkins. I've read quite a few posts about this error and understand that this is generally due to long running requests such as non-selective SOQL queries, bad practice like SOQL in for loops, and other various items that could cause tests/code to go over the CPU governor limits.

My current setup is as follows:

1. Using [Intellij IDEA Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) with the [Illuminated Cloud Force.com Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7831) to complete development work in a Developer sandbox.
2. Pushing commits, when ready to a [Git](https://git-scm.com/) feature branch
3. When the feature is ready, merging the appropriate commits to the QA branch
4. [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) is watching the QA branch for commits and when one comes in it fires off a job to push the metadata to the QA Developer Pro sandbox
5. The Jenkins job first connects to Git to pull the last commit which works great. It then [dynamically builds the Package.xml](http://kevinbromer.com/2013/03/dynamically-building-package-xml/) file via a Bash script, also working great. Finally, Jenkins is calling [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and the [Force.com Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool) to push the metadata, which fails.

Build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce" default="sf" basedir=".">
  <target name="Build">
    <echo>Continuous Integration Build</echo>
    <property file="build.QA.properties"/>
    <property environment="env" />
    <echo>${build.cmd}</echo>
    <antcall target="${build.cmd}" />
  </target>
  <target name="DeployAndCheckOnly">
   <echo>Deploy Code CheckOnly in Org with username: ${sf.username}</echo>
    <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" deployRoot="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA Git Branch to QA Salesforce Org\workspace" logType="Detail" checkOnly="${sf.checkOnly}" />
  </target>
  <target name="DeployAndRunAllTests">
    <echo>Deploy and RunAllTests in Org with username: ${sf.username}</echo>
    <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" deployRoot="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA Git Branch to QA Salesforce Org\workspace" logType="Detail" runallTests="${sf.runallTests}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

build.QA.properties:

```
## build.properties
sf.username = myname@mydomain.com.qa
sf.password = supersecretpassword
sf.serverurl = https://test.salesforce.com

## settings to change in branch properties
## copy the build.master.properties to build.[branch].properties
sf.runallTests = false
sf.checkOnly = true
build.cmd = DeployAndCheckOnly
```

Package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
    <members>MyCustomExtension</members>
    <members>MyCustomWrapper</members>
    <members>MyCustomREST</members>
  </types>
  <types>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
    <members>MyCustomGrandchildObject__c</members>
    <members>MyCustomChildObject__c</members>
    <members>MyCustomObject__c</members>
  </types>
  <types>
    <name>ApexPage</name>
    <members>MyCustomPage</members>
  </types>
  <version>35.0</version>
</Package>
```

Resulting messages from Jenkins:

```
[Slaesforce Build Files] $ cmd.exe /C '"ant.bat -file build.xml "-DC=Program Files (x86)JenkinsSlaesforce Build Filesbuild.QA.properties" Build && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
Buildfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\Slaesforce Build Files\build.xml

Build:
     [echo] Continuous Integration Build
     [echo] DeployAndCheckOnly

DeployAndCheckOnly:
     [echo] Deploy Code CheckOnly in Org with username: myname@mydomain.com.qa
[sf:deploy] Request for a deploy submitted successfully.
[sf:deploy] Request ID for the current deploy task: 0Af29000000i0kvCAA
[sf:deploy] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Pending
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Failed

BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\Slaesforce Build Files\build.xml:8: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\Slaesforce Build Files\build.xml:12: Failed to process the request successfully. Cause(UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION): REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG: Your request was running for too long, and has been stopped.

Total time: 1 minute 39 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

With a total run time of 1.5 minutes, of which only a fraction of that was "InProgress" I am not sure what could be running too long. I also do not know how I can troubleshoot this issue further. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you try building in another org ?Also try with less components to narrow the cause if the issue?

Comment: I'm starting to think the issue has to do with my folder structure, I have "src" as my root folder in git so when Jenkins wraps my data with the package.xml the "src" folder is not included which is required for the deployment. I'm getting my git structure setup correctly and will post back if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments...

The problem appears to be with how the package contents was being passed to Salesforce. That is, it deployed when directly passed to the Metadata API via workbench as a flat structure, but was failing when the folder structure was included in the zip file.

As per the answer to [Metadata Deploy - Package.xml Failure](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/102550/102), the `deployRoot` folder structure needs to be:

```
+ src
|-- package.xml
  +-- classes
    |-- MyCustomWrapper.cls
    |-- MyCustomWrapper.cls-meta.xml
```

---

Try updating your `sf:deploy` in the build.xml with attributes for:

- pollWaitMillis="10000"

  > The number of milliseconds to wait between polls for retrieve/deploy results. The default value is 10000 milliseconds (ten seconds). For long-running processes, increase this number to reduce the total number of polling requests, which count against your daily API limits.
- maxPoll="200"

  > The number of polling attempts to be performed before aborting. The default value is 200. When combined with the default value of pollWaitMillis (10000), this means the Force.com Migration Tool will give the server process a total of 2,000 seconds (33 minutes) to complete before timing out. The total time is computed as 200 poll attempts, waiting 10 seconds between each.

This will increase the timeout duration.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the same error even with these added.

Comment: And it still fails at about one and a half minutes? What happens if you run the command outside of Jenkins? I.e. If you use ant directly how does the deploy go?

Comment: The consensus in [What causes REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG test errors?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/97355/102) doesn't really isolate a cause that would work for your scenario. As Mohith suggests, try deploying fewer components to isolate the issue. Also try explicitly excluded the tests from running.

Comment: I'll reduce the package.xml to one class and work from there to see if it works.

Comment: I've reduced my package XML to only include MyCustomWrapper which is not dependant on any other classes nor anything in the data model. I'm still seeing Pending for a couple of polls then it sits InProgress for a couple of seconds then fails. Total time of the deploy is maybe 50 - 60 seconds.

Comment: Are you just deploying to a sandbox? If so, can you manually create the `MyCustomWrapper ` apex class directly in the sandbox to see what happens?

Comment: It created successfully

Comment: OK, so it isn't the apex class. It is either the Metadata API or the Force.com Migration Tool causing the problem. Next step would be to try and do the deployment independently against the API. Try using  [Workbench](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench#Metadata) to deploy the apex class.

Comment: So when using the metadata api in workbench I can deploy when my zip structure is flat (no folder for classes, pages, etc) but can not deploy when my zip structure has the expected structure under the src folder. Is this right? It might explain why the build is failing because my deployroot for the build is pointing to the src folder which has another level of folders underneath. Thoughts?

Comment: The metadata API has a setting, something like `singlePackage`. If it is false it will search through the supplied zip for multiple deployments. Can you add your zip structure to the question?

Comment: It appears this was all related to folder structure in my zip file: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102550/metadata-deploy-package-xml-failure Feel free to provide another answer so I can mark as answered (you put in all the work to help me solve this!)

Comment: @techbusinessman I've updated the answer with the requirements around the deployRoot folder structure.