# Metadata Deploy - Package.xml Failure

Tags: metadata-api, deployment

I am currently receiving an error when doing a metadata deploy. I have the following zip file structure:

```
Zip (File)
  --> Classes (Folder)
      --> MyCustomWrapper.cls (Class File)
      --> MyCustomWrapper.cls-meta.xml (Class Metadata)
  --> package.xml (File)
```

My **package.xml** is structured as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
    <members>MyCustomWrapper</members>
  </types>
  <version>35.0</version>
</Package>
```

This is what I get when I deploy the file via the Metadata Deploy in Workbench:

[image: Metadata API Failure]

Why is the deploy looking for a package.xml in the classes folder? Shouldn't it expect the package.xml to be in the root of the zip file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should contain the package within a single folder of the ZIP file, like this:

```
+ Zip File
|-- src
  |-- package.xml
  +-- classes
    |-- MyCustomWrapper.cls
    |-- MyCustomWrapper.cls-meta.xml
```

The system saw a single folder in the ZIP file, and assumed that that was the wrapper folder.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Unfortunately I made two mistakes in my comment, I capitalized the package.xml in my question when it was not capitalized in my deployment and I overwrote my ApexClass with MyCustomWrapper rather than NetSuiteResult. Question has been updated.

Comment: @techbusinessman Everything should be in order if you did that. For completeness, did you try wrapping the entire file in a src folder?

Comment: I did not. I had been thinking about that to see what would happen. I'll try and then let you know what happens.

Comment: You rock, needed to wrap it in a src folder. Thanks!

Comment: @techbusinessman I'll revise this answer to your findings. Glad I was able to help.